# How to remove alert of disable developer mode extension in Google Chrome Portable

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i54yc.png)

I am using my custom extension and load unpacked extension to my Portable Chrome, but it keep showing this pop-up.

I did read this post and someone is answered by using the HIEW view to edit the value of chrome.dll.
But I am stuck on Step 4. I couldn't find the value via F7 key.
[How to get rid of disable developer mode extension pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287907/how-to-get-rid-of-disable-developer-mode-extensions-pop-up/30361260)

Please kindly advise, or any other better solution also much appreciate.

**Portable Chrome Version 72.0.3626.81 (Official Build) (32-bit)**

Comment: "showing this pop-up." - Please either be more descriptive around which pop-up you are talking about or provide a screenshot

Comment: @Ramhound I had added the screenshot.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055651/disable-developer-mode-extensions-pop-up-in-chrome